# Passing strings between activities in Android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm going through a Sam's teach yourself android application development book and I have a main activity that extends a second activity and it's supposed to pass the string data between activities. I'm getting this error in the main activity

```
Method invocation 'activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View... may produce java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My main activity code is below:

```
package com.example.owner.hour2application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
            startIntent.putExtra("com.example.owner.Message","Hello SecondaryActivity");
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my second activity code in which android studio is fussing about Intent saying expression expected and non-static method getStringExtra(java.lang.string) cannot be referenced from a static context

```
package com.example.owner.hour2application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.content.Intent.*;


public class SecondaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);
   Intent = getIntent();
    String message = Intent.getStringExtra("com.example.owner.MESSAGE");
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    messageTextView.setText(message);

}

}
```

Comment: This is a warning, it is not an error !!

Comment: try `getIntent().getStringExtra("com.example.owner.MESSAGE");`

Comment: ok thanks! Learning. I appreciate the clarification!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Method invocation 'activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View... may produce java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This means that if in this line:

```
Button activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
```

the operation `findViewById(R.id.Button)` returns `null`, the next line will throw a `NullPointerException` because `activityButton` value will be `null`. This could  happen if the `id` passed to `findViewById` is not found in the `layout`.

You can check if `activityButton` is not `null` and the message will not show up:

```
    Button activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    if (activityButton != null){
        activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
                startIntent.putExtra("com.example.owner.Message","Hello SecondaryActivity");
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

The second problem: you didn't define a variable name in this line:

```
 Intent = getIntent();
```

You need to name a variable and then use it in the next line:

```
 Intent intent= getIntent();
 String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.owner.MESSAGE");
```

Comment: I have another question please...Method invocation 'TextView messageTextView.setText(message)' may produce java.lang.NullPointerException what does that mean???

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.owner.MESSAGE");
```

Also your original key string didn't have MESSAGE in caps. Change to match.